# framework for showing style guide

Tags: javascript, html, document

In my project, We planned to develop a re-usable component list.

How can I generate formatted documentation for our functions similar to those provided by open source frameworks (eg JQuery).

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: in bootstrap, backbone they showing documents how to use the existing classes or function right, I need to create the same for my project. SO is there any tool to create the same.

Comment: Yes, it's called HTML.

Comment: Is there any predefined opensource tool, SO that I can integrate my code in that to make my work easier.

Comment: I don't think so, but it shouldn't be too difficult, just create a basic website for the navigation and a lot of small pages for each function, then call these pages from you main site using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [YUIDoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/)  or [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/).  I think that's what you're after.

Here is a link to a post that collects together a few more:

[Documenting your open source projects](http://gregfranko.com/blog/documenting-your-open-source-projects/)

Comment: Thanks Nick. This what I expected.